# Way to save the other error message in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I Just want to save this error message in database

[image]

So I run this script

```
BEGIN TRY
        RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 
        'C:\ZZ_SQLBACKUP\DBABackupTracer_20181107_230PM_F_2.BAK'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_LINE () AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 
END CATCH
```

So the query gave me this result

[image]

But the error message 
"The volume on device 'C:\ZZ_SQLBACKUP\DBABackupTracer_20181107_230PM_F_2.BAK' is empty." was not included inside the column

Is there anyway to save that sentence?

Thank you in advanvce :)

Comment: Thanks @Sanal Sunny for edit suggestions

Comment: This looks to be a limitation on capturing info when multiple errors are thrown, as it's only showing the last error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222119/sql-server-2005-error-message-not-showing-full-message

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to script it, but it is a bit unconventional, and you need admin rights to run the `dbcc` command.  You cannot use a `try..catch` block, because the error you want to capture is a client-only message.  So, the message must be sent back to the client.  You can then pull the last output sent to the client and place it in a table somewhere for analysis.  For instance:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\ZZ_SQLBACKUP\DBABackupTracer_20181107_230PM_F_2.BAK'
if @@error = 3013
begin
  declare @tbl table (err_msg nvarchar(max))

  insert into @tbl
  execute ('dbcc outputbuffer(@@spid)')

  select top 50 * from @tbl
end
```

If the backup fails, then the output buffer is captured and sent to the table.  Otherwise the output buffer is ignored.  I included `select top 50 * from @tbl` so you could see how the output buffer is formatted.  It isn't pretty, but it does include the full text of the error.

If you want to save the error in a permanent table, you will likely want other columns too, so that you can pull just the data for the most recent error(s).  Change `select top 50 * from @tbl` to something like:

```
insert into your_error_log_table (row_id, database_name, error_date, error_msg)
select row_number() over (order by (select 1)), 'your db name', getdate(), err_msg
from   @tbl
```

Another solution would be to script the backups to run from a Command Prompt or Power Shell and pipe/capture the output to a log file.  That would certainly make the error message more readable.